# to copy data from text file to excel for specific dates

Tags: vba

I have a wonderful VBA code which is successfully copying the data from text file to excel.

The text file contains data of multiple dates and the pattern of date is 05Oct22 (no space in between dates). Each line starts with this pattern (e.g.)

[07] Wed 05Oct22

[03] Wed 05Oct22

[07] Wed 05Oct22

etc.

I would like to request if there is any way to copy the data for specific dates only. let suppose the text file has data ranging from 10Aug22 till 10Oct22 and if i want to copy all the data for 8Oct22 only.

The code i have is mentioned below

```vb
    Sub CopyData()


Dim fileDia As FileDialog
Dim i As Integer
Dim done As Boolean
Dim strpathfile As String, filename As String

'--> initialize variables here

i = 1

done = False

Set fileDia = 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fileDia

    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & 
"\Documents"

    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    .Filters.Clear

    .Title = "Navigate to and select required file."

    If .Show = False Then

        MsgBox "File not selected to import. Process 
Terminated"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    '--> you need to iterate to the files selected, open and 
dump each in your current wb

    Do While Not done

        On Error Resume Next

        strpathfile = .SelectedItems(i)

        On Error GoTo 0



        If strpathfile = "" Then
            done = True
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Reading [ask] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: ok IKE let me raise my question  again

Comment: Dear @Ike Please see my question again. thanks